# Webpart to archive selected documents in a Sharepoint 2007 document library

Tags: web-part, document-library

I am new to Sharepoint.

Currently using Sharpoint 2007 for doing some POC on archiving selected documents in a document library.

I added a column to Document library as Archive, which is Check box. Default value is un-checked(NO)

I want to create a web part to display (in a list box) the documents in that documents lib, from which I can select the documents required and click some button there. With the button click the selected documents status of Archive will become "Yes".

I'm not getting how to begin and where to begin.